# Hover to pause marquee Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a line of scrolling text running across the page of a website Im working on, Im trying to make the text movement pause when the user hovers over it, can anyone advise on how to adjust the jQuery code to achieve this please?

```js
// Start marquee
$('.marquee_text').marquee({
    direction: 'left',
    duration: 50000,
    gap: 50,
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    duplicated: true,
    startVisible: true
});
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

body {
    color: #231815;
    font-family: system-ui, monospace;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee_text {
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 7rem;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.Marquee/1.5.0/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<div class="marquee_text">This text flows right to left by jQuery marquee Plug-In. That direction and speed can optionally be changed.</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#pauseonhover) of the marquee library, as referenced in the top of the JS file, you'll see it has a `pauseOnHover` property you can use for this exact purpose.

```js
$('.marquee_text').marquee({
  direction: 'left',
  duration: 50000,
  gap: 50,
  delayBeforeStart: 0,
  duplicated: true,
  startVisible: true,
  pauseOnHover: true // add this:
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  color: #231815;
  font-family: system-ui, monospace;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee_text {
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 7rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.Marquee/1.5.0/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<div class="marquee_text">This text flows right to left by jQuery marquee Plug-In. That direction and speed can optionally be changed.</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help