# Marquee Hover Pause

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouse, marquee

How can I pause/stop to marquee with mouseover and continue mouseout? is it possible with jquery?

```js
function Marquee(selector, speed) {
    const parentSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
    const clone = parentSelector.innerHTML;
    const firstElement = parentSelector.children[0];
    let i = 0;
    console.log(firstElement);
    parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
    parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
    setInterval(function () {
      firstElement.style.marginLeft = `-${i}px`;
      if (i > firstElement.clientWidth) {
        i = 0;
      }
      i = i + speed;
    }, 0);
}
window.addEventListener('load', Marquee('.marquee', 0.9))
```

```css
.marquee{overflow:hidden;border-top:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;display:flex}
.marquee h1{font-size:5em;white-space:nowrap;text-transform:uppercase}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
   <h1>Nepal * Himalayas * Mountains * Everest * </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hover to pause marquee Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576900/hover-to-pause-marquee-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Marquee(selector, speed, position) {
    const parentSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
    const clone = parentSelector.innerHTML;
    const firstElement = parentSelector.children[0];
    if(position === undefined) i = 0;

    firstElement.onmouseover = function(event) {
      clearInterval(h1Animation);
    }
  
    firstElement.onmouseout = function(event) {
      Marquee(selector, speed, i);
    }
    parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
    let h1Animation = setInterval(function () {
      firstElement.style.marginLeft = `-${i}px`;
      if (i > firstElement.clientWidth) {
        i = 0;
      }
      i += speed;
    }, 0);
}
window.addEventListener('load', Marquee('.marquee', 0.9))
```

```css
.marquee{
  overflow:hidden;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  display:flex;
  }
.marquee h1{font-size:5em;white-space:nowrap;text-transform:uppercase}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
   <h1>Nepal * Himalayas * Mountains * Everest * </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: After pulling the mouse over it, it goes back to the beginning, is it possible to continue from where it left off?

Comment: Let's create a counter on the first call. For subsequent ones, it will take the values of the counter. ----> Edited the code